# Climbing roses -zone 5a or 6 (Canada) -how do I prevent them from dying back ? I want them to ...climb!

Tags: roses

OK this is their second year and I noticed that in the previous year the stems froze and they turned dead in spring

TThey are almost 4 feet now with a spectacular growth in August September, and I want to save that for the next year

How do I protect roses over winter so they can resume the growing from where they stopped the previous year ?

update: here is the picture, the fence is 6'+ 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](https://www.wallishgreenhouses.ca/winter-protection-roses/) you can read some rose protection recommendations from an Alberta source where they have rather more severe winters, and wildly fluctuating spring temperatures that can be as damaging as the absolute cold, than in much of Canada and certainly colder than your specified zone.

Since many roses are grafted, the first thing to check is that your wonderful new shoots actually come from the top part of the rose and not the root. If these shoots are root suckers then this would explain their vigour, but might not be worth saving particularly if you put a lot of work into protection. This is where a picture of your plant actually comes in very handy, readers can see what the situation is and adjust their suggestions.

If the shoots are truly from the good top part of the rose then building protection to four feet will require some work. You might be looking at a compromise to save a few feet less for greater manageability when building a protective structure and filling with dead leaves and finally covering with snow. Resist the temptation to uncover too early in the spring, late frosts can be a real surprise.

Comment: as far as I understand the suckers won't produce the same flowers, the stems that I am looking to protect had flowers as "advertised" when we bought them. I do have this problem with another rose I did not know about grafting when I bought the house, I relocated the rouse and it indeed grew like crazy and made some small white flowers (wild rose I guess) This year it came back (the grafted portion) and I am looking for way to deal with that and to recover the plant

Comment: ok I added a picture